# Magento Error Warning: Undefined property: stdClass::items in ORN.php

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.4

[image]

Response validation: Before accessing the items[0] property of the response object, it is important to check if the items array is empty to avoid errors.

```
/**
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    private function getContact(ORNInterface $orn, $returnId=false)
    {
        try {
            $requestData = json_decode($orn->getRequest());
            $queryUrl = "select id from contacts where contacts.emails.address='" . $requestData->email ."'";
            $query = "queryResults?query=" . urlencode($queryUrl);
            $this->addHeaders();
            $this->curl->get($this->ornConfigData->url . $query);
            $response = json_decode($this->curl->getBody());
            $responseItems = $response->items[0];
         
            if($responseItems->count > 0) {
                if($returnId) {
                    return $responseItems->rows[0][0];
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
$result = false;
$responseItems = $response->items[0] ?? null;

if($responseItems && $responseItems->count > 0) {
    if($returnId) {
        $result = $responseItems->rows[0][0];
    } else {
        $result = true;
    }
}

return $result;
```

Explanation of improvements:

Existence check: **The null merge operator (`??`)** is used to check if **$responseItems** exists before accessing its properties. This prevents errors if $response->items is empty or if element **`[0]`** does not exist.

Additional existence check: Added an extra validation to check if **`$responseItems`** is null before accessing **`$responseItems->count`**. This ensures that the property is only accessed if **`$responseItems`** exists and prevents potential errors.

With these enhancements, you ensure that your code more robustly handles cases where the response is empty or does not contain the expected elements, avoiding unexpected errors.